# Flattening multiple objects in a JSON file

Tags: python, json, flatten

I am trying to flatten a JSON using python, but many JSON files have more than one object and due to this, the python script is not able to flatten it.

Eg:

```
{........
} {
 ......
}
```

There are 3000 files where this is an issue, I can't even manually go and put [] brackets and make it a list, how can I flatten such JSON files please?

Current Code I am using:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import glob
import os
import csv
import xlsxwriter
counter=0
counter1=0

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('......', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
path  = '/Users/.......''
dataframeLS = []
for subfolder in os.listdir(path):
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join (path+subfolder, '*.json')):
        with open(filename) as f:
            try:
                data = json.load(f)
                dataframeLS.append(data)
                counter1=counter1+1

            except:  
                counter=counter+1
                pass

A = pd.io.json.json_normalize(dataframeLS, errors = 'ignore')
A.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
print(counter)  # number of files with error
print(counter1) # number of flattened files successfully
```

Comment: Can you show an example of some code? It will be easier to help you.

Comment: I think I get the issue but it'd be better if you put some examples like an input json file, actual output and the expected output :)

Comment: Sorry guys this is my first post, have added the code which I am using, thanks

Answer (score 0):

So a sample file would look like this ?

```
{
   "temp":1
}
{
   "temp":2
}
```

To import this into python, you could read the file as text first and then fix the syntax errors. If you use a regex, you can deal even with irregular whitespace.

The regex looks like this:

```
}[^,]*{
```

- `}` matches a closing `}`
- `[^,]` matches any character except `,`
- `[^,]*` matches as many characters except `,` as possible
- `{` matches the opening `{`

Together, this matches a pair of brackets with no comma between them.
You can use the regex to replace this text with properly formatted text:

```
import json
import re

file = open("bad_json.json", "r")
text = file.read()
file.close()

text # '{\ntemp:1\n}\n{\ntemp:2\n}'

# we convert it to an array
# add outer brackets
text = "["+text+"]"

# use the regex to replace bad formatting
pattern = re.compile(r"}[^,]*{")
new_text = re.sub(pattern,"},{", text)


data = json.loads(new_text)
```

Comment: Hi, solution is not working bcos of irregular whitespaces spaces between two curly brackets, any solution on how to solve this pls ?

Comment: Hi @lhk, the sample file is actually looking like this:
{
   "temp":1
} {
   "temp":2
} 
Like the end of temp 1 curly bracket and the start of temp 2 curly bracket are on the Same Line and not on the another line, I hope this info makes some difference, as the code is still not working.

Comment: That's strange. If I take your sample (the one from your comment, brackets on the same line) and plug it into my code, it works just fine. You can test it by replacing the file loading part with text = '{ "temp":1 } { "temp":2 }' . Did you copy my exact code ?

Comment: Yes, its working, but there are two things happening:
1) The double quotes " Key ": " Value" , gets converted into single quotes ' Key' : ' Value'
2) I am trying to validate using JsonLint, its showing an error : Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined', which I googled and someone on StackOverflow mentioned this " JSON string literals must use normal quote characters ("), not smart quotes (“”) ", but after running the code, 1) is happening !!

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. My code doesn't replace any quotes, so this should be related to your handling of the JSON data. You are loading it from a file, giving it to my regex and parsing it with json.loads(...), right ? But then you have a python object, so you shouldn't care about the quotes. If JSONLint is complaining about the files you are loading, that seems like a separate question.